# Is it possible to coax std::atomic<T> to output CMPXCHG16B

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, c++11, icc

Is it possible to coax std::atomic to output CMPXCHG16B for types where I'm not interested in using the atomic interlocked operations on Windows x64, or do I just have to suck it up and do the atomic operations by hand? I can get GCC/Clang to do this on Linux so I suspect its just an issue with the Microsoft Standard Library.

```
struct Byte16
{
    int64_t a, b;
};

std::atomic<Byte16> atm;
Byte16 a = { 1, 2 };
atm.compare_exchange_strong(...); // This has a lock on Windows, not on Linux version of code
```

Comment: Processor compatibility?  Some older CPUs don't have that instruction: maybe you need to compile for a narrower target?

Comment: @Yakk I've considered that, however I'm having trouble identifying what flags to pass into ICC. .

Comment: Tried [these options](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-tools-for-software-developers-intel-compiler-options-for-sse-generation-and-processor-specific-optimizations)?  Start with the most "powerful" and see if it solves your problem?  I am just guessing and googling here.

Comment: @Yakk Both /QxHost and /arch:AVX still fails to produce a lock-free std::atomic.

Comment: It looks like it is indeed a Microsoft Standard Library issue. Going through the headers there are only specializations up to 8Byte atomics.

Comment: For future readers, [here's pure C++ `std::atomic<struct>` code that compiles to `lock cmpxchg16b`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984153/implement-aba-counter-with-c11-cas/38991835#38991835) with gcc or clang with `-mcx16` to enable use of that instruction (which is unfortunately not baseline for x86-64: missing from the earliest CPUs).

Comment: You say you know how to do this on GCC, @BlamKiwi.  What is that way?  On gcc 9.2.1, -mcx16 does _not_ work:  "The compiler uses this instruction to implement __sync Builtins.  However, for __atomic Builtins operating on 128-bit integers, a library call is always used."

Comment: @SwissFrank Is this an error or a warning? I haven't used GCC for C++ in a couple of years, but the libatomic library is intended behaviour.

Comment: `boost::atomic` could be a working alternative

Answer (score 1):

In 2024 it is still not possible to have lock-free `std::atomic<Byte16>` in MSVC.

The wide availability of `lock cmpxchg16b` is already recognized, but due to ABI compatibility between VS 2015 and VS 2022 (and everything in the middle), it is not possible for maintainers to redefine the `std::atomic` structure until the next ABI change.

However, as `std::atomic_ref` was added later, it was able to use `lock cmpxchg16b` from the start. It will still use it conditionally, based on CPU check. To bypass CPU check, compile with `_STD_ATOMIC_ALWAYS_USE_CMPXCHG16B` defined to `1`.

You can bundle together `std::atomic_ref` with an underlying value in a single object, if you need exactly `atomic` rather than `atomic_ref`, like this:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct atomic_x : std::atomic_ref<T>
{
    template<class... A>
    atomic_x(A ... a) : std::atomic_ref<T>(Value), Value(a...) {}

    alignas(std::atomic_ref<T>::required_alignment) T Value;
};
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/jvqd3f71K

---

Note that such 16 byte `std::atomic_ref` will `lock cmpxchg16b` even for loads and stores. It may be possible to make them plain load and stores -- see [SSE instructions: which CPUs can do atomic 16B memory operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7646018/2945027) -- but this is not made in MSVC STL (yet).

Comment: It's nearly 10 years and I'm still disappointed.

Answer (score -3):

use __m128 in windows

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
//...
  std::atomic<__m128> a, c;
  __m128 b;
  a.compare_exchange_strong(b,c);
///...
```

Comment: `std::atomic<__m128> atom;
 assert(atom.is_lock_free());` fails.

Comment: then you need to use win32 API InterlockedCompareExchange128.

Comment: I know. I was asking if there was a way avoid having to do all that jazz manually.