# C++ undefined reference to `__atomic_load_16'

Tags: c++, gcc, atomic

I have linking errors, when trying to do an atomic load of a 16 byte block.  I have the following code:

```
#include <atomic>

struct MyStruct{
  long x; long y;
};

struct X{
  std::atomic<MyStruct> myStruct;
};

int main(){
  X x;
  MyStruct s = atomic_load(&x.myStruct);
}
```

When I compile this with (g++ version 5.3.1):

```
g++ --std=c++11 test.cpp
```

I get the error

```
/tmp/ccrvzLMq.o: In function `std::atomic<MyStruct>::load(std::memory_order) const':
test.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt6atomicI8MyStructE4loadESt12memory_order[_ZNKSt6atomicI8MyStructE4loadESt12memory_order]+0x1c): undefined reference to `__atomic_load_16'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If (following a hint in another post) I add the "-latomic" flag, I get the error "/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libatomic.so.1.1.0".  And indeed that file does not exist.

Any suggestions?

Gavin

Comment: Install the atomic library using your package manager.

Comment: Try `-march=native`?

Comment: Your hardware does not have native support for 16-bit atomic operations.

Comment: @KerrekSB That worked, thanks!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik His hardware probably has, but GCC is very conservative with backwards compatibility to old X86/X64 CPUs. The compiler makers don't want code to break, because you compile on a new machine and then later run it on a less abled machine.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem for Clang compiler, in short word: install libatomic and linking with it. (In RHEL the library named `libatomic.so.1` so you may need to `-l:libatomic.so.1` to set the name)

https://releases.llvm.org/14.0.0/tools/clang/docs/Toolchain.html#libatomic-gnu

If compiler don't know how to translate your 'c++_atomic_operation_code' into CPU instruction, it would ask for help from libatomic. The default compile arguments make the program **runnable on x86/64 CPU more generally**, so some CPU instructions are disabled.

On the other side, using libatomic would have chance to execute more mordern instruction with faster speed, see comments below. Thanks for [@Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes)

Within `-march=native`, the compiler could utilize more instruction set to translate code. (your CPU are better than `Generial-x86/64-CPU`)

Or linking with `libatomic` to avoid assigning `-march`.

For example, with using tbb, it would often asked for libatomic to make algorithm generally.

Comment: GCC7 and later [always call to libatomic for 16-byte load/store](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2017-01/msg02344.html), even if you use `-mcx16`.  This turned out to be a lucky decision since libatomic can choose at run-time to use `movaps` on CPUs that support AVX, sine Intel at least has recently documented that the AVX feature bit implies 16-byte atomic load/store guarantees.  ([SSE instructions: which CPUs can do atomic 16B memory operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7646018))