# symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: __atomic_load

Tags: c++, atomic

I am defining an atomic variable of a struct type and the code compiles fine, but when I call the `load()` method on the atomic variable, I get a symbol lookup error. What am I doing wrong?

```
struct Foo
{
  double baz;
  double bar;
};

std::atomic<Foo> atomic_foo {Foo {1.0, 2.0}};

auto foo {atomic_foo.load()};  // <-- symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: __atomic_load
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613415/c-undefined-reference-to-atomic-load-16

Comment: linker needs `-latomic` https://www.godbolt.org/z/7z6414