# Need help resolving linker error for a Yocto recipe

Tags: c++, c++11, yocto, stdatomic, yocto-recipe

so i have a source package that uses std atomic, and currently i am seeing linker erroers while building, the error i am seeing is

```
| /opt/workspace/foo/build-sim-debug/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/bar/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/11.2.0/ld: src/CMakeFiles/FooImpl.dir/xxx.cpp.o: in function `std::atomic<xxx_handle>::load(std::memory_order) const':
| /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/atomic:285: undefined reference to `__atomic_load_16'
| /opt/workspace/foo/build-sim-debug/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/bar/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/11.2.0/ld: src/CMakeFiles/FooImpl.dir/xxx.cpp.o: in function `std::atomic<xxx_handle>::store(xxx_handle, std::memory_order)':
| /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/atomic:271: undefined reference to `__atomic_store_16'
| /opt/workspace/foo/build-sim-debug/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/bar/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/11.2.0/ld: /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/atomic:271: undefined reference to `__atomic_store_16'
| /opt/workspace/foo/build-s
[buildfarm-ssh] im-debug/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/bar/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/11.2.0/ld: /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/atomic:271: undefined reference to `__atomic_store_16'
| /opt/workspace/foo/build-sim-debug/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/bar/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/11.2.0/ld: src/CMakeFiles/FooImpl.dir/xxx.cpp.o: in function `std::atomic<xxx_handle>::load(std::memory_order) const':
| /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/atomic:285: undefined reference to `__atomic_load_16'
```

While researching i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613415/c-undefined-reference-to-atomic-load-16) link which does state that for some compilers you need to pass `-latomic` , my current recipe is like this but i am still seeing the same issue, would greatly appreciate if someone can provide pointers what i might be doing wrong here

```
SUMMARY = "FooImpl"
DESCRIPTION = "FooImpl Recipe"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
 
DEPENDS = "fooInterface googletest framework"
 
SRC_URI = "git://FooImpl;protocol=ssh;branch=mainline;"
SRCREV = "yyyy"
 
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
 
inherit cmake

TARGET_LDFLAGS += " -latomic "
LDFLAGS += " -latomic "
TARGET_CFLAGS += " -march=native "
CFLAGS += " -march=native "
```

i also see `LDFLAGS = "-L ${RECIPE_SYSROOT}"` as well in some searches but i am not sure what it does and whether i should do that for this recipe. Thanks in advance.

---update---

from the logs it does seem like `-latomic` and `-march=native` is getting passed, so i am not sure what could be the issue

```
[buildfarm-ssh] l/git-r0=/usr/src/debug/fooimpl/git-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/workspace/foo/build-sim-debug/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/fooimpl/git-r0/recipe-sysroot=                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/workspace/foo/build-sim-debug/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/fooimpl/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native=   -latomic  -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now  -latomic  -Wl,-zdefs -Wl,-zrelro -Wl,-znow -Wl,--whole-archive,/opt/workspace/foo/build-sim-debug/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/fooimpl/git-r0/fooimpl-git/src/libFooInterface.a,--no-whole-archive -T/opt/workspace/foo/build-sim-debug/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/fooimpl/git-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/ff/ff.ld -shared -Wl,-soname,libFooImpl.so -o src/libFooImpl.so src/CMakeFiles/FooImpl.dir/xxx.cpp.o src/CMakeFiles/FooImpl.dir/discovery_ipc.cpp.o  -Wl,-rpath,"\$APMF-/opt/workspace/foo/build-sim-debug/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/fooimpl/git-r0/fooimpl-git/_ff_components:"  src/libFooInterface.a  /opt/workspace/foo/build-sim-debug/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/fooimpl/git-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libip.so.0.1.0  /opt/workspace/foo/build-sim-debug/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/fooimpl/git-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libff.so && :
| FAILED: src/libFooImpl.so
```

----second update--------

so if i make the change in CMakeList of FooImpl package and add `-latomic`, it builds fine but for some reason it is not working when i try to pass that through recipe, does anyone know what i might be doing wrong and how to pass it through the recipe

---third update----

FooImpl/src/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(lib FooImpl)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(xxx CONFIG REQUIRED)


add_library(${lib} SHARED
  yyy.cpp
  zzz.cpp
)

target_include_directories(${lib} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

target_link_libraries(${lib} PUBLIC FooInterface xxx) <--- adding atomic here makes the build happy
```

Comment: Does `std::atomic<int>::store(...)` work? If yes, maybe `sizeof(xxx_handle)` is too large for atomic. What is `sizeof(xxx_handle)`?

Comment: yes it works, as mentioned in the update of the issue, if i make the change in the CMakeLists of the package itself and remove all of these TARGET_LDFLAGS, LDFLAGS changes that i am trying to make in the recipe than the build succeeds but trying to pass through recipe is not working for some reason and i am not sure why.

Comment: @pts i added the CMakeLists file in the question to provide more context, is `TARGET_LDFLAGS += " -latomic "
LDFLAGS += " -latomic "` the right way to pass these flags to that target