# What x86 CPUs, if any, still have MOVDIRI or MOVDIR64b instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, intel, amd-processor

I've recently been checking the Intel CPUs that I have access to.
None of them (they're all Xeons) have the MOVDIRI or MOVDIR64b instructions, which are store instructions that bypass the caches. Are there any CPUs that do have them? I also wonder why they were introduced if the non-temporal hint has a similar effect.

Comment: Allegedly [Tremont](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54919280/why-doesnt-ice-lake-have-movdirx-like-tremont-do-they-already-have-better-ones) Atoms have those. And I see cpuid reporting support for both on a Core i5-12500.

Comment: Are you running inside a VM?  VMs can and do filter CPUID.

Comment: AFAIK, the reason they were introduced was a reliable way to generate a 64-byte PCIe write transaction.  `movntdq` can result in a smaller transaction if the write buffer gets evicted early, which can happen with a mix of loads and stores, perhaps especially on the low-power Silvermont-family cores they were first introduced in.  Also, kernel code often wants to avoid using any XMM registers, and 8x `movnti` is rather a lot, vs. 4x `movntdq` or 2x AVX `vmovntdq`.

Comment: I've been using AWS Xeons as of late. I also emulate in Qemu.

Comment: Speaking of MOVNTI, that's for writing data. Do you know what the nontemporal main register load instruction is?

Comment: @thequestioner: Remember to @ notify people so they see replies.  The only NT load is SSE4.1 / AVX2 `[v]movntdqa`.  On current CPUs, it only does anything special when loading from WC memory (uncacheable, write-combining).  e.g. for copying from video RAM back to the CPU.  Otherwise it's just a slower `movdqa` load that also costs an ALU uop.  [What is the difference between MOVDQA and MOVNTDQA, and VMOVDQA and VMOVNTDQ for WB/WC marked region?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19035677)