# `is_always_lock_free` gives `true` but `is_lock_free()` gives `false` on macOS, why?

Tags: c++, macos, clang, lock-free, stdatomic

I'm experimenting with C++ atomic's [`std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_always_lock_free) and [`std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free).

I wrote a simple struct `A` and want to know if the atomic version of `A` is lock-free:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

struct A {
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
};

int main() {
  atomic<A> b;

  cout << boolalpha;
  cout << "b.is_always_lock_free = " << b.is_always_lock_free << endl;
  cout << "b.is_lock_free = " << b.is_lock_free() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

On a **x86-64** Linux, I compiled it with **g++ 9.4.0** and C++17, the output is normal:

```
b.is_always_lock_free = false
b.is_lock_free = false
```

However, I also compiled it with **clang++ 16.0.0** on my Mac (**ARM64**), the output is strange:

```
b.is_always_lock_free = true
b.is_lock_free = false
```

Why `is_always_lock_free = true` and `is_lock_free = false`? If it can always be lock-free, why `b` is not lock-free?

Comment: And at least with clang 14 on MacOS, the type *is* in fact lock free, and loads and stores give you a simple `ldp/stp` (which is atomic on ARMv8.4).

Comment: Just for the record on why GCC on x86-64 reports non-lock-free for types >8 bytes but <= 16, even with `-march=native` (on machines with `-mcx16`): GCC7 always avoids inlining `lock cmpxchg16b` and reports non-lock-free because it doesn't have the expected read-side scaling: readers contend with each other.  https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2017-01/msg02344.html .  This might perhaps change once GCC starts taking advantage of Intel's 16-byte load/store atomicity guarantees, retroactively documented in the last couple years, for Intel CPUs with the AVX feature flag.

Comment: for the record, C++20 standard in section 31.8.2 states that The return value of the `is_lock_free` member function is consistent with the value of `is_always_lock_free` for the same type.

Comment: @helix  it can be situational with concrete platform\implementaitons where suddenly atomic requirementis greater than  alignment of `std::atomic<T>` in this unit, Note that  `is_always_lock_free`  is a constant for all compile-units and apparently determined by clang before translation starts, but modules can be compiled with different settings, which doesn't cause problem in this particular case (a local variable). But it can, if that's a shared one. `is_lock_free()` is a function. I wonder if result would be same if  variable would be global and in other unit.

Comment: Can anyone reproduce? I don't have an ARM for testing but the assembly code, both OP's version and my minimized version, shows that `b.is_always_lock_free` resolves to 0. https://godbolt.org/z/xP3z54acz

Comment: @yyyy: Yes, I can confirm that on MacOS 13.6 on an M1 Pro laptop, using clang++ 15.0.0 from Apple's command line developer tools with `-std=c++20`, the output is `true / false`.  Godbolt won't help here because it compiles most things in a Linux environment, and this issue comes from the MacOS system libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bug in the standard library **libc++** (that is not present in libstdc++). Effectively it calls the builtin:

`atomic_always_lock_free` with `sizeof(__cxx_atomic_impl<A>)` which is `16`,

whereas it calls

`atomic_is_lock_free` with `sizeof(A)` which is `12`,

thus yielding inconsistent results.