# why are CAS / other common operations limited to fractions of a cache line?

Tags: cpu-architecture, atomic, compare-and-swap

My understanding is that

- CAS, FAA, and similar operations usually operate on the machine word size (e.g. 64 bits).
- The hard parts of implementing these operations in hardware has to do with communication/synchronization/caches/etc across cores.
- All cross-core communication is already in units of cache lines, which are a multiple of the machine word size (e.g. 64 bytes vs 64 bits).
- There is such a thing as double width CAS (e.g. CMPXCHG16B), so there is clearly some need for bigger-than-machine-word atomics, and ability to implement them.
- However there is no quad-width or octo-width (e.g. 32bytes, 64bytes) CAS (I think?)
- Similarly there is no vectorized (e.g. SSE or AVX) CAS (I think?)

Why do larger CAS sizes not exist? Is it 100% because they are weird and no one thinks of a use for them, or are there implementation difficulties? To me it seems like the implementation comes "for free" for widths up to the cache line size, so they may as well be provided by the hardware.

Comment: Good question, but one of your points isn't *univerally* true: *All cross-core communication is already in units of cache lines, which are a multiple of the machine word size (e.g. 64 bytes vs 64 bits).* - not true on all microarchitectures.  AMD K10 had 16-byte load/store execution units, so `movaps` could atomically read or write L1d cache, but tearing could be observed at 8-byte boundaries between cores on different sockets (not within a single socket).  [SSE instructions: which CPUs can do atomic 16B memory operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7647825) shows experimental evidence.

Comment: But K10 supported `lock cmpxchg16b` (it was only missing in very early AMD64 CPUs I think), presumably with something less horrible than bus locking, so clearly that difficulty isn't insurmountable, and presumably it costs at most an extra cycle of latency for current Intel CPUs to wait for a whole line to arrive over the 32-byte ring bus (in non-server chips) between cores.  I wonder if being an atomic RMW instead of pure store had something to do with K10's HyperTransport not resulting in observable tearing?  Like holding the cache-lock for multiple cycles before the store appears?

Comment: sure, but I'm not really asking about obscure edge-case architectures, I'm interested in common modern architectures.

Comment: Like I said, good question, but one reason for architects not to introduce something like this is that it somewhat constrains the design of interconnects between cores.  Except for Intel, where (unlike AMD) they already guarantee no tearing for unaligned loads/stores to cacheable memory as long as they don't cross a cache-line boundary.  Oh right, **cacheable** memory.  If `lock cmpxch64B` existed, it would have to(?) be supported on uncacheable memory as well, not just playing MESI tricks.  There is `movdir64B` (move-direct atomic 64B store, intended for generating PCIe packets.)

Comment: But yeah, your argument makes sense if we're just talking about cacheable memory.  It would need more microcode to compare multiple register-widths of data, which means holding a cache lock for a few more cycles.  For most algorithms, people have found ways to do them which only rely on atomic load/store/RMW with the width of two pointers, which is what most architectures provide now, but wider might help for some cases?

Comment: (Providing *only* CAS without pure-load / pure-store kind of sucks, as we saw with x86-64 before Intel finally documented that the AVX feature bit implies 16-byte atomicity for `movdqa` etc.  Some other ISAs have similar limitations, needing e.g. `ldrexd` / `strexd` just to do a 64-bit atomic load on some 32-bit ARM CPUs.  And support for efficient pure-loads and pure-stores that still take a cache-lock to give atomicity over multiple microcoded accesses would be something new.)

Comment: Intel's TSX (transactional memory) solved the more general problem by allowing transactions on multiple cache lines.  If they hadn't kept disabling it in microcode (or having OSes do so for vulnerabilities like TAA), by now it would probably be fairly widely available.  Although not on AMD CPUs.  And that's only one vendor for one ISA, so still a valid question.  I assume at least a perceived lack of demand for the feature is part of the reason, since it seems technically doable, especially if you document such an instruction as faulting on memory that isn't (write-back?) cacheable.

Comment: @PeterCordes cool, thanks for the additional information