# Efficient method to check for matrix stability in CUDA

Tags: cuda, pycuda, iteration

A number of algorithms iterate until a certain convergence criterion is reached (e.g. stability of a particular matrix). In many cases, one CUDA kernel must be launched per iteration. My question is: how then does one efficiently and accurately determine whether a matrix has changed over the course of the last kernel call? Here are three possibilities which seem equally unsatisfying:

- Writing a global flag each time the matrix is modified inside the kernel. This works, but is highly inefficient and is not technically thread safe.
- Using atomic operations to do the same as above. Again, this seems inefficient since in the worst case scenario one global write per thread occurs.
- Using a reduction kernel to compute some parameter of the matrix (e.g. sum, mean, variance). This might be faster in some cases, but still seems like overkill. Also, it is possible to dream up cases where a matrix has changed but the sum/mean/variance haven't (e.g. two elements are swapped).

Is there any of the three options above, or an alternative, that is considered best practice and/or is generally more efficient?

Comment: Many reductions use shared memory and compute one result per threadblock. The threadblock results then go through a second "global" reduction.  It seems like something similar could be applied.  It's not difficult to make it thread-safe and less costly if you can work with simply knowing whether a change has occurred rather than the number of changes or which elements have changed.  Then you can simply set a shared memory location to zero at first and let any thread in the block set it to 1, at any time, in any order.  A similar approach can be used for the 2nd step global reduction.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what the actual stability or convergence criteria you need is?

Comment: @talonmies No modifications to the matrix in the last iteration.

Comment: @RobertCrovella similar idea to 3), which is what I'm doing right now (albeit directly on the matrix instead of on a "flags" matrix). I just can't wrap my head around the fact that such a "complex" process is needed when in the best case scenario a boolean flag would have to be modified _once_.

Comment: If you only require an indication of no modifications, you should be able to do this with a single boolean flag, even on the GPU.  The flag sits in global memory.  At the beginning of each iteration it is set to zero.  Any thread detecting a change when updating it's matrix element sets the flag to 1.  No atomics, no reduction.  Check the flag at the end of the iteration.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Might this cause problems if two threads attempt to write to global memory at the same time? talonmies suggests that it might in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416374/several-threads-writing-the-same-value-in-the-same-global-memory-location).

Comment: I don't know of a hazard there, but I assume he's worried about global sync issues.  One hazard is the L1 caches aren't coherent.  There are steps that could be taken to eliminate these issues, especially since you have a well-defined concept of an iteration.  It's difficult to say in a comment, but for example I think most concerns could be eliminated in this case with appropriately inserted instructions to invalidate the L1 and force a flush to L2, for the flag location.  Atomics have a similar effect.  Would need a better idea of your code and who is looking at the flag to comment further.

Comment: talonmies advice is good.  It may not be worth the trouble to pursue this method, and so my comment about using a single boolean flag in global memory might be ill-advised, if care is not taken.  I don't know enough about the structure of your code especially with respect to iterations of the algorithm.

Comment: @talonmies any thoughts? It seems like atomic operations are consistently 10-100x more efficient than doing a sum-reduce on the matrix. However, I'm afraid this will become a bottleneck when scaling up to larger inputs.

Comment: @louism: I had actually written you an answer for this some days weeks ago including some demo code, but a browser crash ate it, sorry. I would do a sum-reduce, but you can do it efficiently using warp voting primitives (the `__any()` warp vote for example). Then you only need a very simple reduction for the result of each warp within a block, and a single atomic add per block to update a global flag. If the flag is in zero copy memory, then you don't need an explicit copy to inspect the result on the host.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks a lot, that definitely points me in the right direction. Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "If the flag is in zero copy memory, then you don't need an explicit copy to inspect the result on the host"?

Comment: Zero copy memory (aka "pinned mapped") is host memory mapped into the gpu address space over the pci  express bus. You don't need to use a copy to read it back the host, the gpu does it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll also go back to the answer I would have posted in 2012 but for a browser crash.

The basic idea is that you can use warp voting instructions to perform a simple, cheap reduction and then use zero or one atomic operations per block to update a pinned, mapped flag that the host can read after each kernel launch. Using a mapped flag eliminates the need for an explicit device to host transfer after each kernel launch.

This requires one word of shared memory per warp in the kernel, which is a small overhead, and some templating tricks can allow for loop unrolling if you provide the number of warps per block as a template parameter.

A complete working examplate (with C++ host code, I don't have access to a working PyCUDA installation at the moment) looks like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <assert.h>

__device__ unsigned int process(int & val)
{
    return (++val < 10);
}

template<int nwarps>
__global__ void kernel(int *inout, unsigned int *kchanged)
{
    __shared__ int wchanged[nwarps];
    unsigned int laneid = threadIdx.x % warpSize;
    unsigned int warpid = threadIdx.x / warpSize;

    // Do calculations then check for change/convergence 
    // and set tchanged to be !=0 if required
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int tchanged = process(inout[idx]);

    // Simple blockwise reduction using voting primitives
    // increments kchanged is any thread in the block 
    // returned tchanged != 0
    tchanged = __any(tchanged != 0);
    if (laneid == 0) {
        wchanged[warpid] = tchanged;
    }
    __syncthreads();

    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        int bchanged = 0;
#pragma unroll
        for(int i=0; i<nwarps; i++) {
            bchanged |= wchanged[i];
        }
        if (bchanged) {
            atomicAdd(kchanged, 1);
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    const int N = 2048;
    const int min = 5, max = 15;
    std::vector<int> data(N);
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        data[i] = min + (std::rand() % (int)(max - min + 1));
    }

    int* _data;
    size_t datasz = sizeof(int) * (size_t)N;
    cudaMalloc<int>(&_data, datasz);
    cudaMemcpy(_data, &data[0], datasz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    unsigned int *kchanged, *_kchanged;
    cudaHostAlloc((void **)&kchanged, sizeof(unsigned int), cudaHostAllocMapped);
    cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void **)&_kchanged, kchanged, 0);

    const int nwarps = 4;
    dim3 blcksz(32*nwarps), grdsz(16);

    // Loop while the kernel signals it needs to run again
    do {
        *kchanged = 0;
        kernel<nwarps><<<grdsz, blcksz>>>(_data, _kchanged);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize(); 
    } while (*kchanged != 0); 

    cudaMemcpy(&data[0], _data, datasz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaDeviceReset();

    int minval = *std::min_element(data.begin(), data.end());
    assert(minval == 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Here, `kchanged` is the flag the kernel uses to signal it needs to run again to the host. The kernel runs until each entry in the input has been incremented to above a threshold value. At the end of each threads processing, it participates in a warp vote, after which one thread from each warp loads the vote result to shared memory. One thread reduces the warp result and then atomically updates the `kchanged` value. The host thread waits until the device is finished, and can then directly read the result from the mapped host variable.

You should be able to adapt this to whatever your application requires

Comment: It's not clear to me how is it possible to evaluate the change undergone by a matrix without a topology. To generate a topology, one needs a norm and [matrix norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) generally require reduction operations. So, I would say that the only way to answer the question on a solid theoretical background is to evaluate the norm of the difference between the matrices at the current and the previous iteration steps by reduction and then set a flag if the norm of the difference exceeds some prescribed accuracy?

Comment: The implicit assumption here is that every thread emits at least one entry in the output. Therefore, each thread is capable of determining whether its output changed through the course of one kernel run (and that was the given requirement in comments). The criteria to determine how a change should be detected is application specific and mostly irrelevent. All the code above does is reduce a thread scope status flag in the cheapest way possible for the host to know whether further iteration is required.

Answer (score 3):

I'll go back to my original suggestion.  I've updated [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416374/several-threads-writing-the-same-value-in-the-same-global-memory-location) with an answer of my own, which I believe is correct.

create a flag in global memory:

```
__device__ int flag;
```

at each iteration,

1. initialize the flag to zero (in host code):

   ```
   int init_val = 0;
   cudaMemcpyToSymbol(flag, &init_val, sizeof(int));
   ```
2. In your kernel device code, modify the flag to 1 if a change is made to the matrix:

   ```
   __global void iter_kernel(float *matrix){

   ...
     if (new_val[i] != matrix[i]){
       matrix[i] = new_val[i];
       flag = 1;}
   ...
   }
   ```
3. after calling the kernel, at the end of the iteration (in host code), test for modification:

   ```
   int modified = 0;
   cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&modified, flag, sizeof(int));
   if (modified){
     ...
     }
   ```

Even if multiple threads in separate blocks or even separate grids, are writing the `flag` value, as long as the only thing they do is write the same value (i.e. 1 in this case), there is no hazard.  The write will not get "lost" and no spurious values will show up in the `flag` variable.

Testing `float` or `double` quantities for equality in this fashion is questionable, but that doesn't seem to be the point of your question.  If you have a preferred method to declare "modification" use that instead (such as testing for equality within a tolerance, perhaps).

Some obvious enhancements to this method would be to create one (local) flag variable per thread, and have each thread update the global flag variable once per kernel, rather than on every modification.  This would result in at most one global write per thread per kernel.  Another approach would be to keep one flag variable per block in shared memory, and have all threads simply update that variable.  At the completion of the block, one write is made to global memory (if necessary) to update the global flag.  We don't need to resort to complicated reductions in this case, because there is only one boolean result for the entire kernel, and we can tolerate multiple threads writing to either a shared or global variable, as long as all threads are writing the same value.

I can't see any reason to use atomics, or how it would benefit anything.

A reduction kernel seems like overkill, at least compared to one of the optimized approaches (e.g. a shared flag per block).  And it would have the drawbacks you mention, such as the fact that anything less than a CRC or similarly complicated computation might alias two different matrix results as "the same".