# CUDA programming: bitwise count rowwise

Tags: cuda, bit-manipulation

I am in some trouble in arranging the threads according to my 2D data array.

It is a compact array where every integer contains 32 bit values `[1000110001000000010000000000010]` representing transactions and I need to count the bits row wise(I have used integer instead of bit vector/bitset). Array is of dimension `1000*3125`. Every row contains 1 lakh bit values.

I need to count total bits that are set to 1 for each row ie. for 3125 columns in each row. How should I arrange the threads/ loop for optimum performance?

Comment: The answer to this post [Efficient method to check for matrix stability in CUDA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443968/efficient-method-to-check-for-matrix-stability-in-cuda/23941330#23941330) on how performing bitwise reduction using vote intrinsics could be helpful to you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [standard parallel reduction approach](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction). You would do one parallel reduction per row of your matrix. The only difference is that each thread will need to pick up a 32-bit value and compute the number of set bits first.

Counting the set bits is easy using the `__popc()` [intrinsic](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT_1g43c9c7d2b9ebf202ff1ef5769989be46), which returns the number of bits set in a 32-bit parameter.

For the parallel reduction part, if you're looking for the fastest possible performance use [CUB](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/) instead of writing your own.