# Unable to find simple sum of 1 to 100 numbers in CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda

I am working on image processing algorithm using CUDA. In my algorithm i want to find sum of all pixels of image using CUDA kernel. so i made kernel method in cuda for measure sum of all pixels of 16 bit gray scale image, but i got wrong answer.
So i make simple program in cuda for find sum of 1 to  100 numbers and my code is below.
In my code i got not exact sum of that 1 to 100 numbers using GPU, but i got exact sum of that 1 to 100 numbers using CPU. So what i had done in that code ?

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <limits>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

__global__ void computeMeanValue1(double *pixels,double *sum){

        int x = threadIdx.x;

        sum[0] = sum[0] + (pixels[(x)]);
        __syncthreads();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double *data;
    double *dev_data;
    double *dev_total;
    double *total;

    data=new double[(100) * sizeof(double)];
    total=new double[(1) * sizeof(double)];

    double cpuSum=0.0;

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        data[i]=i+1;
        cpuSum=cpuSum+data[i];
    }
    cout<<"CPU total = "<<cpuSum<<std::endl;

    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_data, 100 * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_total, 1 * sizeof(double));

    cudaMemcpy(dev_data, data, 100 * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    computeMeanValue1<<<1,100>>>(dev_data,dev_total);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaMemcpy(total, dev_total, 1* sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cout<<"GPU total = "<<total[0]<<std::endl;

    cudaFree(dev_data);
    cudaFree(dev_total);

    free(data);
    free(total);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sum[0] = sum[0] + (pixels[(x)]);` will cause race condition. Use atomics instead. Also, if the program is not for test purpose, I would recommend using **NPP** for image reductions.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use atomics? This will effectively serialize all your threads as they wait to get access to the `sum[]`. I think a reduction is the right way to go about this.

Comment: The CUDA reduction sample code is step-by-step documented also in the [CUDA Handbook](http://www.cudahandbook.com/). It could be useful to you to take a look at different strategies (using atomics or no) to perform reduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your threads are writing to the same memory location at the same time.

```
sum[0] = sum[0] + (pixels[(x)]);
```

You can't do this and expect to get the correct result. Your kernel needs to take a different approach to avoid writing to the same memory from different threads. The pattern usually employed for doing this is reduction. Simply put with a reduction each thread is responsible for summing a block of elements within the array and then storing the result. By employing a series of these reduction operations its possible to sum the entire contents of the array.

```
__global__ void block_sum(const float *input,
                          float *per_block_results,
                          const size_t n)
{
  extern __shared__ float sdata[];
  unsigned int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

  // load input into __shared__ memory
  float x = 0;
  if(i < n)
  {
    x = input[i];
  }
  sdata[threadIdx.x] = x;
  __syncthreads();

  // contiguous range pattern
  for(int offset = blockDim.x / 2;
      offset > 0;
      offset >>= 1)
  {
    if(threadIdx.x < offset)
    {
      // add a partial sum upstream to our own
      sdata[threadIdx.x] += sdata[threadIdx.x + offset];
    }

    // wait until all threads in the block have
    // updated their partial sums
    __syncthreads();
  }

  // thread 0 writes the final result
  if(threadIdx.x == 0)
  {
    per_block_results[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
  }
}
```

Each thread writes to a different location in `sdata[threadIdx.x]` there is no race condition. Threads are free to access other elements in `sdata` because they only read from them so there are no race conditions. Note the use of `__syncthreads()` to ensure that the operations to load data into `sdata` are complete before the threads start to read the data and the second call to `__syncthreads()` to ensure that all the summation operations have completed before copying the final result from `sdata[0]`. Note that only thread 0 writes its result to `per_block_results[blockIdx.x]`, so there is no race condition there either.

You can find the complete sample code for the above on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/stanford-cs193g-sp2010/source/browse/trunk/tutorials/sum_reduction.cu) (I did not write this). This slide deck has a reasonable summary of [reductions in CUDA](http://mc.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/images/5/55/Darve_cme343_cuda_4.pdf). It includes diagrams which really help in understanding how the interleaved memory reads and writes do not conflict with each other.

You can find lots of other material on efficient implementations of reduction on GPUs. Ensuring that your implementation makes most efficient use of memory is key to getting the best performance out of a memory bound operation like reduction.

Answer (score 1):

In GPU code, we have multiple threads executing in parallel.  If all of those threads attempt to update the same location in memory, we have undefined behavior, unless we use special operations, called `atomics` to do the update.

In your case, since `sum` is updated by all threads, and `sum` is a `double` quantity, we can use the [special custom atomic function described in the programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) to accomplish this.

If I replace your kernel code with the following:

```
__device__ double atomicAdd(double* address, double val)
{
    unsigned long long int* address_as_ull =
                              (unsigned long long int*)address;
    unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;
    do {
        assumed = old;
        old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed,
                        __double_as_longlong(val +
                               __longlong_as_double(assumed)));
    } while (assumed != old);
    return __longlong_as_double(old);
}

__global__ void computeMeanValue1(double *pixels,double *sum){

        int x = threadIdx.x;
        atomicAdd(sum, pixels[x]);
}
```

And initialize the `sum` value to zero before the kernel:

```
double gpuSum = 0.0;
cudaMemcpy(dev_total, &gpuSum, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Then I think you'll get matching results.

As @AdeMiller pointed out, the faster way to perform parallel sums like this is via classical parallel reduction.

There is a CUDA sample code that [demonstrates this](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction) and an [accompanying presentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) that covers the methodology.