# Parallel writes of a same value

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, race-condition, memory-model

I have a program which spawns multiple threads that may write the exact same value to the exact same memory location:

```cpp
std::vector<int> vec(32, 1); // Initialize vec with 32 times 1
std::vector<std::thread> threads;

for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; ++i) {
    threads.emplace_back([&vec]() {
        for (std::size_t j = 0 ; j < vec.size() ; ++j) {
            vec[j] = 0;
        }
    });
}

for (auto& thrd: threads) {
    thrd.join();
}
```

In this simplified code, all the threads may try to write the exact same value to the same memory location in `vec`. Is this a data race likely to trigger undefined behavior, or is it safe since the values are never read before all the threads are joined again?

If there is a potentially hazardous data race, will using a `std::vector<std::atomic<int>>` instead with `std::memory_order_relaxed` stores instead be enough to prevent the data races?

Comment: It is actually fairly easy to determine if something is data-race-UB or not: If more than one write, but no read, can be executed at the same time, you're in trouble. If more than one read, but no write happens, you're fine. If one write and at least one read happens at the same time, you're screwed again. Short: (>1 write) OR (write+read) is trouble.

Comment: Use atomics and you're safe. I see no reason to introduce UB here.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8315931)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Language-lawyer answer, [intro.multithread] n3485

> <sup>21</sup> The execution of a program contains a *data race* if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads,
>   at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in
>   undefined behavior.
>
> <sup>4</sup> Two expression evaluations *conflict* if one of them modifies a memory location and the other one
>   accesses or modifies the same memory location.

---

> will using a `std::vector<std::atomic<int>>` instead with `std::memory_order_relaxed` stores instead be enough to prevent the data races?

Yes. Those accesses are atomic, and there's a *happens-before* relationship introduced via the joining of the threads. Any subsequent read from the thread spawning those workers (which is synchronized via `.join`) is safe and defined.

Answer (score 4):

It is a data race and compilers will eventually become smart enough to miscompile the code if they are not already.
See [How to miscompile programs with "benign" data races](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/hotpar11/tech/final%5ffiles/Boehm.pdf) section 2.4 for why writes of the same value break the code.

Comment: This was intended as a comment to the Language-lawyer answer by dyp to show that it actually has consequences, but I lack the required reputation.

Answer (score 1):

**Implementation detail answer:**

While the language standard classifies this as undefined behavior, you can actually feel quite safe as long as you are really writing the same data.

Why? The hardware sequentializes accesses to the same memory cell. The only thing that can go wrong is when several memory cells are written at the same time, because then you have no guarantee by the hardware that the accesses to several cells are sequentialized in the same way. For example, if one process writes `0x0000000000000000`, and another writes `0xffffffffffffffff`, your hardware may decide to sequentialize the accesses to the different bytes differently, resulting in something like `0x00000000ffffffff`.

However, if the data written by both processes is the same, then there is no noticeable difference between the two possible serializations, the result is deterministic.

Modern hardware does not handle memory accesses in a byte by byte fashion, instead, CPUs communicate with the main memory in terms of cache lines, and cores can usually communicate with their caches in terms of 8-byte words. As such, setting a properly aligned pointer is an atomic operation which can be relied on to implement lockfree algorithms. This has been exploited in the Linux kernel before more powerful atomic operations became available. C++ formalizes this in the form of `atomic<>` types, adding support for the more high level hardware features like write after read, atomic increments and such.

But, of course, if you rely on your hardware details, you really should know what you are doing before you do it. Otherwise stick to language features like the `atomic<>` types to ensure proper operations and avoid UB.

---

**@Downvoters:**

The question is *not* tagged [language-lawyer], and the answer explicitly states "Implementation detail answer". It was intentional to explain what the UB in the program will look like in real life. This answer has been written to complement the accepted answer (which has my upvote) with a different perspective on the question.

Comment: You also cannot rely on the compiler to not exploit the UB. The loop is essentially a memzero. Who knows what the compiler does to that?

Comment: @usr Well, the optimizer can usually be relied on not to understand concurrency issues. It would make optimization far too complex, and the only effect would be to break multi-threaded code. And there is no UB behavior in the loop when you assume that there is only one thread.

Comment: "Why? The hardware sequentializes accesses to the same memory cell." You have an oracle that knows every kind of hardware upon which the OPs program will ever run?

Comment: @Casey No, I don't, but I know how bytes are transfered to main memory; and I even have a bit of a notion about what is feasible in hardware, and what is not. Consequently, I'm quite certain that the OP's program will never run on a hardware where two concurrent writes of the same data lead to undefined behavior. But, of course, this is the implementation detail answer :-)