# How to properly use openMP

Tags: c++, performance, openmp

I am trying to speed up my MPI project by utilizing openMP. I have a dataset of 1000 2d points, and am using a brute force algorithm to find the minimum distance in the 2d graph. When I try to split the thread of execution, however, it greatly hurts the performance.How can I properly utilize openMP?

Here is my attempt:

```
double calcDistance(double input[][2], int start, int stop){

    double temp;
    //declare and initialize minimum
    double minimum =  pow (((input[start+1][0]) - (input[start][0])),2) + pow(((input[start+1][1]) - (input[start][1])),2);
    minimum = sqrt(minimum);

    closestIndex1 = start;
    closestIndex2 = start+1;
    //Brute Force Algorithm to find minimum distance in dataset.

        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(int i=start; i<stop;i++){
            for(int j=start; j<stop;j++){

                    temp = pow(((input[j][0]) - (input[i][0])),2) + pow(((input[j][1]) - (input[i][1])),2);
                    temp = sqrt(temp);
                    if(temp < minimum && i < j){
                            minimum = temp; 
                            closestIndex1 = i;
                            closestIndex2 = j;
                    }//endif
            }//end j
          }//end i
return minimum;
}
```

I have to say WOW. Thank you, that was incredibly helpful, and really cleared up a bunch of questions that I had. Again, thank you,  gha.st.

Comment: Does the program give the right answer? Don't you need something like `#pragma omp critical` before `return minimum` to force it to wait until all threads are complete? It also seems like you need some private variables - does the program give the same answer every time it is run?

Comment: Yes, the program runs fine, and the answers are correct and always the same. Its just the performance suffers. With just mpi the program exeutes in ~.06-.08s. Adding openmp, ~.5-.8s.

Comment: I added some serial optimizations, giving a 5x speedup in the test case

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Analysis

First, it is *pure luck* that your program seems to work like this. You do indeed have a data race, that causes invalid results on my machine. Consider the following test harness for this post:

```
::std::cout << ::xtd::target_info() << "\n\n"; // [target os] [target architecture] with [compiler]

static const int count = 30000;
auto gen = ::std::bind(::std::normal_distribution<double>(0, 1000), ::std::mt19937_64(42));
std::unique_ptr<double[][2]> input(new double[count][2]);
for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    input[i][0] = gen();
    input[i][1] = gen();
}

::xtd::stopwatch sw; // does what its name suggests
sw.start();
double minimum = calcDistance(input.get(), 0, count);
sw.stop();
::std::cout << minimum << "\n";
::std::cout << sw << "\n";
```

When executing your function with the omp pragma removed, its output is:

```
Windows x64 with icc 14.0

0.0559233
7045 ms
```

or

```
Windows x64 with msvc VS 2013 (18.00.21005)

0.0559233
7272 ms
```

When executing it with the omp pragma intact, its output is:

```
Windows x64 with icc 14.0

0.324085
675.9 ms
```

or

```
Windows x64 with msvc VS 2013 (18.00.21005)

0.0559233
4338 ms
```

Since the machine uses 24 threads (on 12 cores with HT enabled), the speedup is evident, but could possibly be better, at least for msvc. The compiler that generates a faster program (icc) also shows the data race by giving wrong results which are different each run.

Note: I was also able to see an incorrect result from msvc, when compiling a debug version for x86 with 10k iterations.

#### Proper usage of iteration-local variables

The `temp` variable in your code has a lifetime of one iteration of the innermost loop. By moving its scope to match its lifetime, we can eliminate one source of data races. I also took the liberty of removing two unused variables and changing the initialization of `minimum` to a constant:

```
double calcDistance(double input[][2], int start, int stop){
    double minimum = ::std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    //#pragma omp parallel for // still broken
    for(int i = start; i < stop; i++){
        for(int j = start; j < stop; j++) {
            double temp = pow(((input[j][0]) - (input[i][0])), 2) + pow(((input[j][2]) - (input[i][3])), 2);
            temp = sqrt(temp);
            if(temp < minimum && i < j) minimum = temp;
        }
    }
    return minimum;
}
```

#### A proper OMP minimum computation

OMP has support for [reductions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#Reduction), which will in all probability perform fairly well. To try it, we will use the following pragma, which ensures that each thread works on its own `minimum` variable which are combined using the minimum operator:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(min: minimum)
```

The results validate the approach for ICC:

```
Windows x64 with icc 14.0

0.0559233
622.1 ms
```

But MSVC howls `error C3036: 'min' : invalid operator token in OpenMP 'reduction' clause`, because it does not support minimum reductions. To define our own reduction, we will use a technique called [double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking):

```
double calcDistance(double input[][2], int start, int stop){
    double minimum = ::std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = start; i < stop; i++){
        for(int j = start; j < stop; j++) {
            double temp = pow(((input[j][0]) - (input[i][0])), 2) + pow(((input[j][1]) - (input[i][1])), 2);
            temp = sqrt(temp);
            if(temp < minimum && i < j)
            {
                #pragma omp critical
                if(temp < minimum && i < j) minimum = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return minimum;
}
```

This is not only correct, but also leads to comparable performance for MSVC (note that this is significantly faster than the incorrect version!):

```
Windows x64 with msvc VS 2013 (18.00.21005)

0.0559233
653.1 ms
```

The performance of ICC does not suffer significantly:

```
Windows x64 with icc 14.0

0.0559233
636.8 ms
```

#### Serial optimizations

While the above is a proper parallelization of your serial code, it can be significantly optimized by considering that you are computing a whole bunch of `temp` results you are never going to use due to your `i < j` condition.

By simply changing the start point of the inner loop, not only will this computation be completely avoided, it also simplifies the loop conditions.

Another trick we use is delaying the `sqrt` computation until the last possible second, since it is a homomorphic transformation, we can just sort on the square of the distance.

Finally, calling `pow` for a square is fairly inefficient, since it incurs a ton of overhead that we do not need.

This leads to the final code

```
double calcDistance(double input[][2], int start, int stop){
    double minimum = ::std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = start; i < stop; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < stop; j++) {
            double dx = input[j][0] - input[i][0];
            dx *= dx;
            double dy = input[j][1] - input[i][1];
            dy *= dy;
            double temp = dx + dy;
            if(temp < minimum)
            {
                #pragma omp critical
                if(temp < minimum) minimum = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return sqrt(minimum);
}
```

Leading to the final performance:

```
Windows x64 with icc 14.0

0.0559233
132.7 ms
```

or

```
Windows x64 with msvc VS 2013 (18.00.21005)

0.0559233
120.1 ms
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me about double-checked locking.  That's interesting!  However, I don't think it's the most efficient way to do this reduction.  In the worst case each thread would still have to wait every iteration (making it effectively serial).  A more efficient method is to declare private version of min for each thread and then merge them in a critical section.

Comment: @Zboson Correct, in fact, that is similar to what the `reduction (min: minimum)` solution does internally. In the average case, this simple variant works almost as well with a lot less effort however (as can be seen from the timings).

Comment: I think the double-checked locking only works if writes to `minimum` are atomic.  In that case, you don't need the `critical` pragma.

Comment: @Patrick Yes, atomic writes are [guaranteed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292786/is-updating-double-operation-atomic) and necessary for double checked locking. The `critical` pragma however is needed to guarantee that the second check is valid for the write. One could use [`omp atomic`](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/cref_cls/common/cppref_pragma_omp_atomic.htm) to ensure the atomicity of the write or a [CAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683562.aspx) instead of the critical section.

Comment: @gha.st Yes, you're right about the `critical` pragma.  Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I am didn't understand why there is twice the statement `if(temp < minimum)`. Any good reason for this?

Comment: @BRabbit27 As explained in the answer, it is a technique called [double checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking). The basic idea is to do an optimistic check without locking that only locks (enters the critical section) if there is a **chance** it might work. Inside it of course still has to be checked if it **truly** is ok to pass the guard.